# Modifying single list items

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a ListView, displaying some items, containing an ImageView filled with a standard image at first and a line of text.

What I wanna do is downloading one thumb after another with an AsyncTask and step for step change the standard image with the downloaded one. How to realise this?

The ListView contents are managed by an enhanced ArrayAdapter.

greetz

EnflamedSoul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're interested in a LazyList. This example shows a stub for the image, then downloads some thumbnails as the user scrolls down and caches these onto an SD card. The next time the images will be loaded from the SD card.

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

I personally used Fedor's example and it worked well.